# Linear Algebraic Groups with Same Lie Algebra (Soft Question)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

Let $G$ and $H$ be two linear algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $F$ (char 0 ) such that their lie algebras are isomorphic. Now what can we say about the relation between these two groups ?

It would appreciate if you could give me a detailed description or refer to some quick notes where I can check this out .

**PS**: I do not know much algebraic geometry and I just needed to know some sort of relation between these 2 groups to continue reading a paper as I am stuck at this point.

Thanks !

Comment: In what sort of generality are you working? Over an algebraically closed field? In characteristic $0$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft   Yes algebraically closed and characterstic 0. I will edit the question ! Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: Hmm, in that case I think this implies that there is an isogeny between them, but I am not completely sure. I think the book by Malle and Testerman "Linear Algebraic Groups and Finite Groups of Lie Type" might be a good reference.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  I just referred Milne's notes on somebody's suggestion. Corollary 3.30 says  "A homomorphism $ G  \to H $ of connected affine algebraic groups is an isogeny if and only if $ Lie(G) \to Lie (H)$ is an isomorphism."    SO, now since in my case the Lie algebras are isomorphic, any surjective homomorphism is an isogeny. But a small doubt may be trivial, how do we know that first of all there exist a surjective homomorhism between them ?

Comment: Ahh, so that almost does it, up to showing that any isomorphism of the Lie algebras actually lifts to a homomorphism of the groups (which I think also holds since we are in the nicest possible case)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  I just referred Milne's notes on somebody's suggestion. Corollary 3.30 says  "A homomorphism $ G  \to H $ of connected affine algebraic groups is an isogeny if and only if $ Lie(G) \to Lie (H)$ is an isomorphism."    SO, now since in my case the Lie algebras are isomorphic, any surjective homomorphism is an isogeny. But a small doubt may be trivial, how do we know that first of all there exist a surjective homomorhism between them ?

Comment: Yes, Milne's lectures were my suggestion. We can find most of the answers we need there.

Comment: When $G,H$ are abelian of the same dimension they have isomorphic Lie algebra but can be different (unipotent $\neq$ torus). So indeed in general there is no surjective homomorphism at all.